# Why people feel outward force in rotor ride?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I know centrifugal is fictious force but what is possible reason for the force that people feel in rotor ride outwards.

The reason for people not falling down is friction force which is in vertical direction so, what is the force in horizontal direction that makes people feel the force on their chest (also the normal force is in inward direction so, it can't be the reason)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you're in a car and stomp on the brakes. If you're not wearing a seat belt you'd describe your motion as "thrown forward," but that's an illusion due to the non-inertial reference frame of the accelerating car.  To an observer on the side of the road, you're moving forward with the same velocity you had before, while the car around you slows down, so that you catch up with the front windshield.

If you're wearing a seat belt, you still have that "thrown forward" sensation, but now you accelerate with the car.  In that case the force you're feeling is the normal force from the seat belt, which is pushing you towards the *back* of the car.  Your intuition gets the direction of the force wrong because of the accelerating reference frame.

It's the same on the rotor ride where the room spins and you stick to the wall.  If not for the wall, you'd move in a straight line and leave the ride.  The force you feel *is* the normal force from the wall pushing you inward; your intuition about the direction is incorrect because you're in an accelerating reference frame.

Comment: "our intuition gets the direction of the force backwards because of the accelerating reference frame."  but you said that we feel force pushing us forward which is true but in these lines you are saying we feel force backwards. I am confused. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PiyushGalav Poor word choice; edited.